# jquery get or post methods for drupal block module

Tags: 7, hooks, blocks, javascript

Is it possible to use jquery get or post methods to fetch data dynamic in a a drupal7.x block module. I am a newbie to drupal.

Here is my event_calendar.module file

```
      function event_calendar_help($path, $arg)
      {
          switch ($path) 
          {
          case "admin/help#event_calendar":
          return '<p>'.  t("A block module that creates events and lists them in a event calendar") .'</p>';
      break;
          }
    }
     /**
    * Implements hook_block_info().
    */
    function event_calendar_block_info() {
      $blocks['event_calendar'] = array(
        'info' => t('Event calendar'), 
        'cache' => DRUPAL_CACHE_PER_ROLE, //Default
      );
      return $blocks;
    }

    /**
    * Implements hook_block_view().
    *
    * Prepares the contents of the block.
    */
    function event_calendar_block_view($delta = '') 
    {
      switch($delta)
      {
        case 'event_calendar':
          $block['subject'] = NULL;
          if(user_access('access content'))
           {
            $items = array();        
            $basepath = drupal_get_path('module', 'event_calendar');
            $markup = '<div id="content">
                    <div style="float:right;margin-bottom:5px">
                        <label style="float:left;padding:3px;">Week :</label>
                        <div id="date_picker">
                            <span id="startDate"></span></span> - <span id="endDate"></span>
                            <div class="week-picker" style="display:none;position:absolute"></div>   
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <hr style="clear:both;"/>
                    <div id="calender_content">

                    </div>
                    <div id="color_code" style="float:right">
                        <div class="lane1 colorbox"></div><div style="float:left">Lane 1</div>
                        <div class="lane2 colorbox"></div><div style="float:left">Lane 2</div>
                        <div class="lane3 colorbox"></div><div style="float:left">Lane 3</div>
                        <div class="lane4 colorbox"></div><div style="float:left">Lane 4</div>
                    </div>
                </div>';
      $block['content'] = array(
        '#markup'   => $markup,
        '#attached' => array
            (
            'css' => array($basepath . '/css/event_calendar.css',$basepath . '/css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css'),
            'js'  => array($basepath . '/javascript/event_calendar.js',$basepath . '/javascript//jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js'),
            ),
        );

          }
return $block;
      }

    }
```

I want to know how to write functions inside above .module file to access some content dynamically through jquery get or post method?

Or should I use something like 'hook_menu' other than block?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For using get data by jquery ajax you need first seta menu link for listen to your ajax requst, and in callback of your menu you passed back a block or any data you want.

```
function yourmodule_menu () {
   $items=array();
   $items['youruniqepath'] =array(
        'title' => 'my menu',
        'description' => 'A menu link to handle ajax request',
        'page callback' => 'yourhandlerfunction',
        'access callback' => TRUE, //you can set it with your permission
      );
   return $items;
   }
```

and in yourhalderjust need pass a block :

```
function yourhandlerfunction () {
  //with any method you want get your block,
  // I suggest something like this
    $block = module_invoke('module_name', 'block_view', 'block_delta');
    print render($block);
}
```

and in your clientside get it with something like this

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'youruniqepath',
    //data: {}, you can also pass block name and act more dynamicly
    success: function (data){
        $('#yourplace').html(data);
    }
});
```